# An approach to solving $2(2^{(a+b+c+2)} + 3\cdot 2^{(a+b+1)} + 9\cdot 2^a + 101)$ for multiples of 77

Tags: elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

In searching for counter examples to the Collatz Conjecture, I have come across a family of equations with the following form.  $$77D = 2(2^{a+b+c+2} + 3 * 2^{a+b+1} + 9 * 2^a + 101)$$ Where $$0>a+b+c<=4$$and$$D>0$$Computationally solving for this example is relatively simple with $$a=1,b=2,c=1, D=6$$and$$a=0, b=1, c=2, D=4$$
However, as the equations of this form become larger and more useful, computation becomes impossible.  Could anyone recommend an approach for determining if equations of this form have a solution? Or more ideally tell me such an approach does not exist, so that I can return to more fruitful endeavors.

Thank you for any time or insight you can provide.

Comment: a first start would be looking at the problem mod 77

Comment: You should return to more fruitful mathematical topics to study. The Collatz fad is nothing more than a total waste of time, not only yours but that of everyone who reads posts about Collatz.

Comment: I thought I appropriately tagged it so that people who weren't interested could tactfully ignore it.  Apology if I did something incorrectly.

Comment: You didn't do anything incorrectly, and that's why I answered your final inquiry (whether to return to more fruitful endeavours). If I didn't think you were sincere I wouldn't give you advice on how to better spend time.

Comment: After attempting to use the mod 77 as @barrycarter suggested, I end up with a reduced equation of:

(8(2^a mod 77 * 2^b mod 77 * 2^c mod 77) + 12(2^a mod 77 * 2^b mod 77) + 18(2^a)) mod 77 = 29

However, I don't feel any closer to a solution.

Comment: ([(8(2^a mod 77 * 2^b mod 77 * 2^c mod 77)mod77] + [12(2^a mod 77 * 2^b mod 77)mod77] + [18(2^a)mod77]) mod 77 = 29

I forget a few mod 77 in the above.  Now that I have a simplified equation, I do not know how to begin solving for a, b and c.  Is there a trick to isolating the exponents?

Comment: You can look at the cycle of numbers created by 2^a (mod 77) for example, and similar for b and c, so you can reduce further mod 77 I think.